# how to get single record per id from one to many related tables in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, one-to-many

I have one to many related tables; a product table, and their images per ProductID. Images can exist for a productID single or more or not at all. So I left outer join them if images not exists, record will be null.

I select them by their category ID which means there can be other products too so I could not use top 1.

my query:

```
select p.ID,p.ProductName,pc.CategoryID, pic.BigPath
from tbl_Products p
LEFT join tbl_ProductToCategory pc on p.ID = pc.ProductID
left outer join tbl_ProductImages pic on pic.ProductID = p.ID
where pc.CategoryID = 1174
```

Above query gets all products with multiple records because of the table ProductImages.

I need to get single record from product image table; ex: one that has min image ID.

Above query gets these:

```
ID   ProductName  CategoryID  BigPath

311  a            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/a..
313  b            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/b..
318  c            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/c1..
318  c            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/c2..
318  c            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/c3..
```

I expect:

```
ID   ProductName  CategoryID  BigPath
311  a            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/a..
313  b            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/b..
318  c            1174        www.blabla.com/cdn/c1..
```

How can I get a single record from ProductImages table?

Comment: Please add sample data with the expected output.

Comment: Move the WHERE clause condition to the (first) ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select p.ID,p.ProductName, p.SalesPrice, pc.CategoryID, pic.BigPath,
row_number() over(partition by p.ID,p.ProductName order by pic.BigPath) as rn
from tbl_Products p
LEFT join tbl_ProductToCategory pc on p.ID = pc.ProductID
left outer join tbl_ProductImages pic on pic.ProductID = p.ID
where pc.CategoryID = 1174
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: But your code gets only one product for that category, I need all products for a category, but single image record per productID. @fa06

Comment: @Zeynep, I've updated the answer - you can check now